# Can't add firebase in component in Vue js

Tags: firebase, vue.js, integration

I'm learning vue.js (version 4.3.1)from documentation a tutorial on the internet, now I'm trying to integrate Vue js with Firebase (   "firebase": "^7.14.0",), but my when I run it, an error says:

> firebase not defined

However, I make it in a single file called firebase.js but when I add the import to components it gives this error.

```
//firebase.js
// Your web app's Firebase configuration
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "********",
    authDomain: "**********",
    databaseURL: "*********",
    projectId: "*********",
    storageBucket: "******",
    messagingSenderId: "******",
    appId: "*******",
    measurementId: "******"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();
```

`

`

```
//login.vue
import firebase from "../firebase"
```

Comment: Hello, have a look at this repo: https://github.com/savvyapps/SAVuegram/tree/master/src

Answer (score 0):

You're not exporting anything in your `firebase.js`. So when you do `import firebase from "../firebase"` in our `login.vue`, the code is imported, but `firebase` doesn't get any value. That then leads to the error message when you try to access `firebase` in your code.

The solution is to export the variables from your `firebase.js` that you want to use in the rest of your app. As shown in the Github link Renaud provided, you can do that with for example:

```
//firebase.js
// Your web app's Firebase configuration
  var firebaseConfig = {
     ...
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();
  export {
    analytics: firebase.analytics(),
    auth: firebase.auth()
  }
```

Or, my personal preference:

```
//firebase.js
// Your web app's Firebase configuration
  var firebaseConfig = {
     ...
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();
  export default firebase;
```

Comment: @ Frank van Puffelen, Thank you so much, I tried this but when I add import firebase from "../firebase in login component, gives the same error.